# How to get absolute file path located in class path when starting application (.jar file) from different directory?

Tags: java, path, processbuilder

Assume that Java application folder has these files:

```
app.jar
lib/file.exe
```

Inside app.jar I call .exe like this:

```
String[] exeCmd = new String[]{"lib/file.exe"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(exeCmd);
...
```

If I start .jar file from the same directory - everything works fine. But if application is launched from different directory - `lib/file.exe` can't be found and `ProcessBuilder` quits with error "no such file or directory".

My question is - how to get right `lib/file.exe` path, and provide it to `ProcessBuilder` despite application is launched from other directories?

**EDIT:**

Now I'm thinking (different aproach) that those .exe like files I should put in user directory, like "Application Data" in Windows OS and later use them? It would be easy to find the path by calling `System.getenv("APPDATA");` or `System.getProperty("user.home");` in Unix. But on the other hand - if there are a lot of PC users - so those .exe files would be duplicated for each user (waste of disk space).

Comment: are you looking something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file?rq=1 ?

Comment: Related, but not the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```